# an angel of a woman VS. a woman like an angel

Tags: rhetoric

> an-angel-of-a-woman >(simplified)> angel of woman: angel came first and woman later; in my point of view, angel is emphasized.

> a woman like an angel >(simplified)> woman like angel: woman came first and angel later; in my point of view, woman is emphasized.

Q: Is there any prefrence and/or difference of the two example phrases? Or, any other customary usage practice for native English speakers or any rhetorical effect of difference for readers or in terms of writers' strategies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**an angel of a woman** is a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) that was common in the 19th century, and has enjoyed a small comeback in the last 20 years.

Here are some typical current usages:

> How Guy Pierce could leave such an angel of a woman as his wife to be with that bold-faced hussy, I can't conceive. - *Is it just? - Minnie Smith 2010*

> Janet Marks- a member of the Wilmette Assembly and an angel of a woman- stopped by to check in on me. - *High Desert - Kim Douglas 2009*

**a woman like an angel** is more [literal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/literal), but is much less common. I can't find any typical usages of "a woman like an angel", recent or otherwise.