# an angel of a woman VS a woman of an angel

Tags: idiomatic-language

> an angel of a woman VS. a woman of an angel

Are these two sentences different in meaning or could one of them be wrong or unidiomatic?

Comment: In what circumstances would you expect to say _a woman of an angel_? _She is an angel of a woman_ means that she is so kind (and, perhaps, beautiful) that she seems like an angel. It's highly unlikely that anyone would admiringly compare an angel to a woman!

Comment: All the angels I've come across have male names - possibly a case of celestial gender discrimination - although I see that there are a great many I've not yet encountered: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_angels_in_theology

Comment: If you want to use 'of a' or 'of an' to state that your opinion that a thing is like some other thing, an angel of a woman (if she is virtuous or kind), a lion of a man (if he is brave), a shoe-box of a house (if it is small), etc, you put the other thing first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [an angel of a woman VS. a woman like an angel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273418/an-angel-of-a-woman-vs-a-woman-like-an-angel)

Comment: Kate. That was my question. The question is different. This question is about order of a word. English order is different from that of my language.

Comment: This question is addressing a different issue than the linked question, and in my view is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic construction is ***a/one + noun (both positive and negative connotations possible) + of a + noun***. One example is:

***One heck/hell of a (something or someone)*** which [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+hell+of+a+woman) defines as:

> 1. An exceptionally good, exciting, or interesting thing or person.
>
> - Marty sure is one hell of a guy, always willing to lend his friends a
>   hand!
>
> 2. An exceptionally bad or difficult thing, activity, or person.
>
> - This is one hell of a math assignment—I can't understand the first thing
>   about it!

I also came across ***a wonder of a woman*** or ***a miracle of a woman***:

> Her smile was loveliness itself … ***a miracle of a woman*** ([Trollope society](https://trollopesociety.org/character/hartletop-griselda-grantly-marchioness/)).

Such expressions basically show that a woman ***is (comparable to)*** a miracle, a wonder, in your case, an angel.

The only case I would see the expression ***a woman of an angel*** possible, would be in a sci fi book or movie about angels, describing one angel's human, feminine side. But that's just imagining.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely different.

"An angel of a woman" is quite idiomatic. It means a woman who has "angelic" qualities, such as kindness, mercy, holiness, and patience.

"A woman of an angel" is not idiomatic.  It would, I suppose, mean an angel with womanly characteristics (but not a woman).  I have no idea how to interpret that.

See also a [discussion on wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/angel-of-a-woman-woman-of-an-angel.2598855/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20set%20idiomatic,a%20womanly%20type%20of%20angel.)

Comment: 'angels of women' means women are like angels? The only difference is plural.